# Question about discrete Topology and discrete metric

Tags: general-topology

Let S be a set. If one defines $\tau=\mathbb{P}(S)$, then $\tau$ is called the discrete Topology. Furthermore the discrete Topology is the topology which is "induced" by the discrete metric.

I am trying to show two things,

1. Tau is topology:

(i)
$\emptyset \in \tau$, $S \in \tau$

(ii)
Let $I$ be any Indexset, and $\tau_i \in \tau$
Because $\tau_i \in S \Rightarrow U:=\cup_{i\in I}\tau_i \subseteq S$ so $U \in \tau = \mathbb{P}(S)$

(iii)
Let $\tau_1,\tau_2 \in \tau$, because $\tau_1, \tau_2 \subseteq S \Rightarrow  \tau_1 \cap \tau_2 \subseteq S \Rightarrow \tau=\mathbb{P}(S)$

2. discrete topology is induced by the discrete metric

Because  $\tau$ is a topology every subset of S is open.

The discrete Metric is defined as,
let M be a Set and d a metric ,then
$d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$
and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y.$

Let x $\in$ M, $0<\epsilon<1$, then $U_{\epsilon}(x)=\{x\}$. So the set $\{x\}$ is open.
The union of these open sets $\{x_i\}$ is again a open set (this comes from the property of metric spaces.)

My Question: Is my proof of 1) and 2) correct?
My Problem with 2) is that for the discrete Metric one needs a "distance function d", which in general does not need to exist in a topological space. What does , "the discrete metric induces the discrete topologie" actually mean? In number 2) I only proofed that every subset of M is open. Is this enough or am I missing something?

Comment: *Where* is your proof of 1)? I was unable to find it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it is under the points (i), (ii), (iii)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the discrete topology on $X$ is induced by the discrete metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218163/show-that-the-discrete-topology-on-x-is-induced-by-the-discrete-metric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The discrete topology is induced by the discrete metric:*

Let $X$ be any set, and let
$$
d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, \quad \text{if } x \neq y \\0, \quad \text{if } x = y \end{cases}.
$$
Let $U_x = \left\{ x \right\}$, which can be written as the ball $B \left(x, \frac{1}{2} \right)$, of radius $1/2$, centered at $x$. In particular, each $U_x$ is open. Now any set $S \subset X$ can be written as
$$
S = \bigcup \limits_{x \in S} U_x.
$$
In other words, all $S$ are open and the topology induced by $d$ is the discrete topology.

In particular, the discrete topology is metrizable (there is a metric that induces it). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483936/what-does-induced-by-a-metric-topology-mean) is some more information about metrizability.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine. Your proof of (1) is a bit thin, but it really doesn’t need much.

I’d quibble with this language, which is not part of the proof, but a definition:

> The discrete Metric is defined as
> let M be a Set and d a metric ,then
> $d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$
> and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y.$

This implies that if $(M,d)$ is *any* metric space, it has the property $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0&x=y\\1&x\neq y\end{cases}$$

The key wording error in your sentence is “then,” which implies a conclusion.

A correct wording is:

> Let M be a set.  Define $d$ for $x,y\in M$ as
> $d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$
> and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y.$ Then $d$ is a metric, called the discrete metric on $M.$

In this new language, we are concluding $d$ defined this way is a metric.